# How to add the symbol §?

Tags: symbols

I would like to use the symbol § as just another variable in some equations.

Is there anyway I can do this easily? All I've seen so far is more complicated for formatting it into references.

**How can I add the symbol § to my equations?**

Comment: That is `\textsection` `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\dagger$ \textsection
\end{document}` You can use https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 2):

You write \S in math mode:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    $\S \quad y=\frac{x}{2x-1}$
\end{document}
```

The outcome:
[image]